# bentorf's angular bootstrap multiselect: clearing selections on click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

We are using [betorf's angular bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/bentorfs/angular-bootstrap-multiselect) on a form that has several other fields.  At the bottom of the form, we have a "Reset" checkbox that we want to clear the form when true.  How can we achieve this with this multiselect?  Our current code looks like this:

```
<multiselect classes-btn="'btn-primary btn-block'" 
             placeholder="Choose your users"
             show-tooltip="true"
             show-search="true" 
             show-select-all="true" 
             show-unselect-all="true" 
             ng-model="c.selection" 
             options="data.users" 
             show-search="true" 
             id-prop="id" 
             display-prop="name">
</multiselect>
```

```js
$scope.$watch(function () {  
    return c.selection;
}, function () {  
    var arr = [];
    console.log(c.selection);
    console.log(c.selection[0].id);
    for(var i =0; i<c.selection.length; i++) {
        arr.push(
            c.selection[i].id
        );
    }
    var users = arr.toString();
    $scope.page.g_form.setValue('u_slush_test',users);

    if($scope.page.g_form.getValue('clear_form')==true){
        c.selection=[];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> we have a "Reset" checkbox that we want to clear the form when true

I recommend that the app use a reset button instead of a reset checkbox:

```
<button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
```

```js
$scope.reset = function() {
     $scope.c.selection = null;
};
```